# Fix git history messiness

Tags: git

I've completely screwed up my history somehow and I now have this monstrosity at the top of my log graph:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all | head
*   9287659 (HEAD -> production, origin/production) Merge branch 'master' into production
|\
| * 7e7237a (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Reports on LaMP validation history now 
* |   a7b2c39 Merge branch 'master' into production
|\ \
| * | d8f2320 Reports on LaMP validation history now - LaMP/LaMP-Service#31
| |/
* | a8c6183 Reports on LaMP validation history now
|/
* caa80f6 T&M report only includes completed assessments.  Added a 'lab' tab to the download
```

My 'master' and 'production' branches should both be pointing to the exact same thing at this point.  What I want my graph to look like is this:

```
* somenum Reports on LaMP validation history now - LaMP/LaMP-Service#31
* caa80f6 T&M report only includes completed assessments.  Added a 'lab' tab to the download
```

HEAD, production, master, origin/production and origin/master should all be pointing at the top line.

I'm the only person with access to this repo so doing an overwrite of the remote repository is fine.

I've tried doing a rebase against `caa80f6` and that just made it worse.

Comment: Looks like you need to merge production back into master unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the only one using it a rebase should be fine. You can squash the commit together.
`git rebase -i caa80f6`
I think this is what you want. 'f' will squash and discard commit messages.

f a8c6183 Reports on LaMP validation history now
pick d8f2320 Reports on LaMP validation history
f a7b2c39 Merge branch 'master' into production
f 7e7237a (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
f 9287659 (HEAD -> production, origin/production)

Comment: This didn't work as the first thing wasn't a pick, but looking at it I realized the easiest thing to do was just 'drop' the weird commits and recreate them.

Comment: Yea I was hopeful but didn't have a chance to verify it. Glad to hear you got it working.